# How to assign values to particular point in 3D rectangle in matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d

I want to animate the varying temperature gradient in 3D rectangle. I have temperature values at specified points in a real container. I am not been able to figure out how to pass the temperature values as specified point in 3D container in Matlab.Lets say I have 10 points on one side of rectangle and same as on other remaining five sides.
any suggestions

Comment: Thanks yuk for answer. I have plotted using your function but I want a gradient temperature , alike blue for the coldest and red for the hottest. Here in this case i get specified points but what about in between those points? how can make them fill with varying color gradient

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that your rectangular container is oriented in space with one vertex at (0,0,0) and sides along x, y and z axis. And you have set of points each with 3-point coordinate (x,y,z). In MATLAB it's probably represented by 3 vectors X, Y and Z. You also have a vector of temperature values (say T) for each points.

Then you can use [SCATTER3](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/scatter3.html) function to plot the points:

```
scatter3(X,Y,Z,[],T,'.')
```

You can change the size of points substituting the empty parameter with a value.

If you have point only on the faces of the container, it means one of the coordinate is either 0 or the size of corresponding side.

the colors are controlled by current color map. You can change it with [COLORMAP](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/colormap.html) function. For temperature the good one is 'hot' or 'cool'. Show the color scale with [COLORBAR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/colorbar.html).

Here is an example with random data:

```
%# random coordinates
X = rand(60,1,1);
Y = rand(60,1,1);
Z = rand(60,1,1);

%# put the points into faces
X(1:10) = 0;
X(10:20) = 1;
Y(20:30) = 0;
Y(30:40) = 1;
Z(40:50) = 0;
Z(50:60) = 1;

%# temperature vector
T = rand(60,1,1) * 100;

%# plot
scatter3(X,Y,Z,[],T,'.')
grid off
box on
colormap hot
colorbar
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Temp=zeros(10,10,10);
Temp(5,2,4)=25;
```